# What are the possible and meaningful measurements on a quantum walk on a graph?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, stochastic-processes, quantum-measurements

In the contest of quantum walks, the graph is defined as $G=\{V,E\}$ with $V$ the set of vertices and $E$ the set of edges. Thus, the Hilbert space is defined as the $\mathcal{H}=\operatorname{span}\{\vert i \rangle, i \in V\}$.

The usual measurement one can consider on quantum states that live on the graph is the position measurement
$$
\hat{M} = \sum_i i \vert i \rangle \langle i \vert
$$
My question is: *are there other possible and meaningful measurements, considering only the position degree of freedom $\vert i \rangle$*?

Just to make an example of what I mean, a possible meaningful measurement could be the position along the $x$ and $y$ axis when the graph is projected on the plane, that is ($N=\deg(V)$)

$$
\hat{M}_x = \sum_i \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{N}i\right) \vert i\rangle \langle i \vert \\
\hat{M}_y = \sum_i \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{N}i\right) \vert i\rangle \langle i \vert
$$

What I’d like to find is a single (or multiple) measurement which can distinguish the nodes in the graph. The problem with, for instance, a measurement of the index is that the variance of this measurement is index dependent and this is actually a problem in graph like the complete graph, where my intuition fails with a variance index dependent

Comment: whether a measurement is "meaningful" entirely depends on what your goal is. Any measurement can be useful for *some* application

Comment: A comment from someone that has no particular knowledge of quantum walks of graphs - is there a reason you don't consider $\hat{Q} = |i\rangle\langle j | + |j\rangle \langle i |$ to be meaningful?

Comment: @glS actually the main reason I’m asking is that i’d like to find a single (or multiple) measurement which can distinguish the nodes in the graph. The problem with, for instance, a measurement of the index is that the variance of this measurement is index dependent and this is actually a problem in graph like the complete graph, where my intuition fails with a variance index dependent

Comment: @jacob1729 at a first sight the problem is that is degenerate measurement

Comment: @raskolnikov that's not the question you asked though. You should edit the post to reflect what you are actually looking for

Comment: @glS I did, hope it is more clear now:)

Comment: @glS yes it does, but if you read below there is a problem with this measurement

Comment: What do you mean by "measurement of the index", and "distinguish the nodes of the graph"? Are these special concepts which need to be defined?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch for "measurement of the index" I mean the position measurement in the question, whose eigenvalues are the index of the nodes, so it is someway dependent on the index one choose, not on the real position, like for instance the projection on x-y plane. Instead, for "distinguish the nodes of the graph" I mean exactly something like the two operators M_x and M_y. I was wondering if there are other possibilities

Comment: In that case, if you interpret your measurement of $M$ as a single-copy measurement, you automatically get a specific $i$ as an outcome if you perform the measurement once on a single system. You only run into "trouble" if what you mean by "measurement" is the measurement of an expectation value, which amounts to measuring many copies of identically prepared systems.  So which of those two do you have in mind (or better, what is the general context of your question)?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch that’s exactly the point, I have mind the second case you are describing, and I’d add the the first case you described is a more “classical situation”. The general context is a little bit difficult to write down in a comment, but just to sum up is continuous measurement (that is, weak measurement)

Comment: On the contrary! The first case is as quantum as it gets, while the second part is more classical. The reason that QM is phrased as measuring expectation values is that this is what you get when you measure *many* particles at once (like spectral lines in a gas), and this is what historically was measured.  But in the end, measuring individual systems, amounting to projecting onto individual outcomes, is the more fundamental quantum mechanical measurement.